# How to test if an Actor is able to receive the message or not?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have the below Actor which receives two messages:

```
class SampleActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "hello" => println("Hello Message")
    case "world"=>println("World Message")
    case _=>println("Unhandled message")
    }
  }
}
```

I want to test if the actor is able to receive the messages "hello" and "world". The examples I have seen do not fulfill this requirement.

The one [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html) and [here](http://roestenburg.agilesquad.com/2011/02/unit-testing-akka-actors-with-testkit_12.html) has the actor sending back a message and using expectMsg() they check the response. But my requirement is to see if the Actor is able to receive the message or not, and not whether the actor is able to respond back with a specific message.

The example [here](https://danielasfregola.com/2015/03/02/how-to-test-actors-with-akka-testkit-and-spec2/) changes the state of the actor and they check the state to see if the actor is able to receive the message. Again, not what I wanted.

So, how do I just test if my actor is able to handle the two messages through TestKit?

Comment: in place where your actor is created use instead `TestProbe`.

Comment: This can easily become a rather philosophical on the actor model itself. 
Essentially you'd want to test that your actor responds to a specific message (or a specific kind of messages). You can ONLY do that by checking that the expected behaviour your actor is supposed to assume takes place after it has received the message. 
That is, for ex., if the actor does IO (ie. replies to the sender somehow) or updates some state.
Your `SampleActor` doesn't do anything.
From the outside world you can always send anything to an actor. It might just do nothing for messages he doesn't care about.